# Is it possible to hide an element in İFRAME?

Tags: css, wordpress, iframe, hide, inspector

I am using an İFRAME on my site [tuning-doc.nl](https://tuning-doc.nl) to select car makes with their horsepower. I would like to hide the following:

**Powered by Tuning-shop.com**

At the top and the bottom. I tried to hide these by CSS in Google Chrome's inspector, but when I save in via the customizer of WordPress's theme, nothing happens and the text is still there.

Can you help me please?

I tried it to hide it through CSS. But it is still there. Inspector is working, but theme not.

Comment: Try this `#iFrameResizer0 .Top.header-background{display:none}`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe)

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job:

```
 .Top__right.header-color { display: none;}
```

But if it does not work you can try:

```
.Top__right.header-color { display: none !important;}
```

Comment: Hi Edgars, thanks for your answer. It works indeed in the inspector, but not in the customizer > CSS

Comment: Hey, I did not know about what Caleb mentioned, that you cannot modify contents of iframes.
Seems like the iframe has a lot of functionality and might be complex to re-create.

One thing I thought of would be to wrap it in an element and have another element with the same color positioned absolutely over it to hide it.

Kinda dirty hack, I know :P

Answer (score 0):

Styles for your site cannot impact elements inside of iframes that are cross-domain. Cross-domain websites embedded in iframes are isolated from your site.

Comment: Is there any other methode to solve this problem: not showing the text?

Comment: Recreate the form and send the results to the proper endpoint.

Comment: I cannot recreate because I don't host it

Comment: You can build it yourself, separate from where it's currently hosted.